# Problem with duplicate class com.google.android.gms Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

i have a problem with :
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1)

Have you idea for resolve this error ?

I give you my app bluid.gradle ....

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'


    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        applicationId "fr.appli.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.adobe.xmp:xmpcore:5.1.2'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.4.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using old versions of these

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

try these newer versions

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the app's "build.gradle" file, add the following along with "android {...}"

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.`'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Such errors are easily resolved by bumping the version of your libraries to the latest ones.

I can see that you're using super outdated versions of following libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

Bump up their versions, and versions of all the other libraries and that should fix the error.

Latest version of both the libraries is `16.0.0`, so you should make it

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If after you updated your libraries as previous users have suggested, you keep seeing the same error, try excluding the **duplicate** module from one  of your libraries. For example:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'{
        exclude group : 'nameOfTheGroupHere', module: 'nameOfTheModuleHere'
    }
```